# Get All order items for admin create order in shipping magento

Tags: php, magento

I am struggling to get order items when admin create order from backend manually. I need it to calculate shipping.

I tried few methods to get all cart items but they didnt work so far,

What I have tried are

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getAllItems()
```

and

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getOrder()->getAllItems()
```

I need to get it when admin click on Get shipping methods and Rates link in create order screen
[image: Get Shipping methods and Rates link in create order screen]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are trying to create a new shipping method.
If that's the case [this may help you](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).
If you follow that tutorial, in the method `collectRates($request)`, that is in charge of calculating the shipping cost you should be able to access the quote items like this:
`$request->getAllItems()`.
The `$request` variable is passed to all the shipping methods and contains among others the items in the quote.

Comment: I am using Fontis Australia post which I customized it from front end depends on items selected by customer, But in backend when Admin create order it doesnt give me items array as like front end. Let me go through the article you sent me, let see if I can find some solution. Thanks.

Comment: So How did you solved that. I followed the mentioned article but didnt figure out to solve that